# What dose it mean when Fawn say "Invalid Condition"

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, npm, mongoose

I init fawn as the document says and still, I'm getting an error message `Invalid Condition`, so what is wrong?
Thanks for the helpers.

```
await new Fawn.Task()
                .save('chefs', chef)
                .update('recipes', targetRecipe.id, { targetRecipe })
                .update('foodcategories', targetRecipe.foodCategory, { recipes: targetRecipe })
                .run();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you init the fawn, use  `Fawn.init("mongodb://localhost/dbName");`

Instead of `Fawn.init(mongoose);`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see on the docs.
[Fawn update][1]
[1]: https://npmjs.com/package/fawn#task_update
The condition must be same as in mongoose and mongodb, so you need to write it like:

```
await new Fawn.Task()
            .save('chefs', chef)
            .update('recipes', { _id: targetRecipe.id }, { targetRecipe })
            .update('foodcategories', { foodCategory: targetRecipe.foodCategory }, { recipes: targetRecipe })
            .run();
```

I dont know if foodCategory is a key on your schema but it is just an example.